# Type mismatch error on VBA with empty cells which contain formulas

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am exporting data from Excel to Access. The data in Excel contains formulas, which are leaving cells blanks with if function: `=IF(SISESTUS!B18="";"";SISESTUS!C18`.

Problem is: VBA is not capable of reading blank cells with formulas.  This raises a type mismatch error. When I copy only values then is ok, my export macro runs perfectly.

Code:

```
Sub Export_Data()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbPath
Dim x As Long, i As Long
Dim nextrow As Long

On Error GoTo errHandler:    

dbPath = ActiveSheet.Range("S3").Value
nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    
If Sheet8.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
MsgBox " Lisa kirjed tellimusse, midagi pole arhiveerida"
Exit Sub
End If
    
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
    
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    
rst.Open Source:="Tellimused", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable    

For x = 2 To nextrow
rst.AddNew
For i = 1 To 16
rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
Next i
rst.Update
Next x
    
rst.Close

cnn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
    
MsgBox " Tellimus on edukalt arhiiveeritud"
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
Sheet8.Range("R3").Value = Sheet8.Range("T3").Value + 1
    
Sheet8.Range("A2:P250").ClearContents
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

errHandler:
    
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"

End Sub
```

I think, after these lines code, macro ends and give a error messages. For clarity.

```
For x = 2 To nextrow
    rst.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 16
    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
    Next i
    rst.Update
    Next x
```

Comment: On which line does this fail precisely?

Comment: Your question is competing with all a lot of others for the attention.  If you can make this easier for us to understand, you are more likely to receive a working answer.  Large code blocks can put people off, as they take time and effort to understand.  Can you replace that code with an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable - see the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on this)?

Comment: For x = 2 To nextrow
    rst.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 16
    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
    Next i
    rst.Update
    Next x

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use some recognizable value in your formula that the macro can read (like 999999) instead of "" and handle it inside macro:

```
If Cells(x, i).Value <> 999999 Then
    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
Else
    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = "" ' or skip
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem with paste if anybody got similar issue:

```
Sub Copy_Data()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:P250").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U2:AJ250").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```